# Send SMS to cellphone using phpmailer

Tags: php, gmail, sms, phpmailer, sms-gateway

I am trying to send **SMS** using **phpmailer** with my **gmail** account.

This is my code:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username   = "myusername@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "mypassword";
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;

$mail->SetFrom('myusername@gmail.com', 'DS');
$mail->Subject    = 'hello';
$mail->Body    = 'this is a testing mail..';
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxxxx@ideacellular.net','testname');

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

`xxxxxxxxxx@ideacellular.net` denotes the `mobilenumber@carrierdomain`.

When I execute this script. Output is that :  **Message sent!**

But the sms is not received.

Please let me know if there is any mistake in my code (or) is it a invalid way to send `SMS` using `phpmailer`.

Using this code (change AddAddress field to email instead of mobile number) I can send mail.

But SMS cant be sent.

**IS this possible to send SMS using phpmailer?**

Please help me to resolve this problem..
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: phpmailer is for email only...usually third party SMS plugin requires fee

Comment: Is the email forwarded to a mobile phone?

Comment: No, email sent to email id(if I provide email id), but I want to send message to mobile(if I provide mobile number)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that issue with 'ideacellular.net'.
Most phone companies have an email gateway which permits you to send an SMS message to their customers via email. You'll need to determine for each service provider what that email address looks like and set up some code to turn their phone number and service provider combination into the appropriate email address.

[image: sms-php]

Check this link:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/

Following code works with verizon

require 'class.phpmailer.php';

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Configure SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();                
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;          // verbose information
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';       

// Auth
$mail->Username   = "email.address@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password   = "password"; 

// Check
$mail->Subject = "Testing";     
$mail->Body = "Testing";        


$mail->AddAddress( "##########@vtext.com" ); 
var_dump( $mail->send() );
```

**UPDATE**

To send a text message from an email, you need to know the address for the SMS gateway. Below is a list of the SMS gateways for some of the major US cellular providers. If a carrier is not in the list, search the website for that carrier and you will likely find their SMS gateway address.

```
AllTel: number@message.alltel.com
AT&T: number@txt.att.net
Boost Mobile: number@myboostmobile.com
Cricket: number@sms.mycricket.com
Nextel: number@messaging.nextel.com
Qwest: number@qwestmp.com
Sprint: number@messaging.sprintpcs.com
T-Mobile: number@tmomail.net
Tracfone: number@mmst5.tracfone.com
U.S. Cellular: number@email.uscc.net
Verizon: number@vtext.com
Virgin Mobile: number@vmobl.com
```

Also, you may check this link for the list of other providers:
http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

Comment: How I know the email address of service providers if I only knows the mobile number?

Comment: I've just updated the post. Check if it could help you.